# Using VAT numbers as partition key to store enterprises in DynamoDB

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a dynamoDB table that will contain a fairly large number (tens of millions) of companies entries that have the following fields:

- VAT number (always unique)
- Company name
- Country code (very limited set, 2 or 3 possibilities)
- Address

To me, the unique VAT number seems like the obvious candidate for a partition key, but since I'm still new to noSQL, I'm questioning my jugement in that area...

Is there a better candidate that I'm not seing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with DynamoDB you should always keep in mind what answer your table has to answer.

Using the `VAT` as partition key is well done, the records will be uniformly distributed in partitions.

By doing that, you'll be able to get in O(1) any item by its `VAT`.

If you want to access the companies by name, `Company name`, it is also a good candidate for partition key, **as long as it is unique**. You can also keep `VAT` as a partition key and create a Global Secondary Index with the partition key `Company name`.

So before designing a DynamoDB table define the queries it has to answer. When you know the queries you are able to choose your partition and sorting keys, as well as defining some Global Secondary Indexes for some supplementary questions.